# Why did Hasbro's Combiner Wars Superion toy originally contain the Decepticon Dragstrip?

Tags: transformers, toys

The original G1 Superion was made up of the five Aerialbots<sup>1</sup>:

[image: G1 Superion]

However, in the latest release from Hasbro, Combiner Wars<sup>2</sup> Superion includes the Decepticon [Dragstrip](http://transformers.hasbro.com/en-gb/combiner-wars/product/transformers-generations-combiner-wars-deluxe-class-decepticon-dragstrip-figure:E12354F5-5056-9047-F5F6-4BE33F71B06F)<sup>3</sup> (in this image, the right arm):

[image: Combiner Wars Superion]

*[Both images from tfnd.net.](http://tfnd.net/discuz/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=35795&extra=page%3D1)*

My question is: **why did Hasbro originally include a Decepticon as part of the makeup?** I cannot remember them previously mixing up a combiner with robots from different allegiances.

Was it a mistake<sup>4</sup>? Or some clever way to sell more toys?

The [main Hasbro site](https://transformers.hasbro.com/en-gb/brands/combiner-wars) shows both Superion made up entirely of Aerialbots and Menasor made up entirely of Stunticons:

[image: Combiner Wars Superion from Hasbro site]

[image: Combiner Wars Menasor from Hasbro site]

And it seems that the [Superion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YEYB3ZE) and [Menasor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZGDIWWO) being sold at Amazon have been updated to sell the correct Transformers, implying it was a mistake.

[Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/the-latest-transformers-line-combines-everything-80s-ki-1677879611) is the only site I've found offering some kind of (unsourced) explanation:

> And finally add in the Decepticon Dragstrip, who's technically part of the Stunticon Combiner Menasor, but winds up puling [sic] cameo duty since Hasbro decided to release one wave with four Autobots and then reverse it later in the year.

This is an incomplete explanation - why would Hasbro only release four Autobots (Aerialbots) and one Decepticon?

Ideally I'm looking for a quote from Hasbro explaining this.

<sub>1 And therefore they are all Autobots.</sub>

<sub>2 Note, there are multiple Superion versions, some from Hasbro and some from other vendors. This is specifically about the *latest* (at time of writing) toy: Hasbro's Combiner Wars Superion.</sub>

<sub>3 Dragstrip is a Stunticon who makes up part of Menasor. He is therefore a Decepticon.</sub>

<sub>4 It could easily be a mistake. Eg another mistake is that the [Hasbro site](http://transformers.hasbro.com/en-gb/combiner-wars/) currently states: *"allows **six** different bots to combine"* whereas actually it is **five**.</sub>

Comment: I'm still looking for something more official, but [BWTF mentioned "production issues" being the cause](http://www.bwtf.com/toyreviews/generations/combinerwars/airraid)

Comment: Man, I've found a handful of forum posts and such mentioning "production issues", but nothing official. Not even a news/blog post about it.

Comment: @phantom42: thx for looking; if it was easy I would've answered it myself! :) I'm wondering if Hasbro are trying to forget it happened.

Comment: it's just really weird. for so many people to be talking about it, the explanation had to have come from somewhere.

Comment: Might be a mistake or a way to show you can mix the transformers forming the bigger ones (Superion, Menasor... ) and you also got a [Optimus Prime](http://www.geekworldordersite.com/blog/2015/01/thats-just-prime-combiner-wars-optimus-prime-combined-mode/) that can form a bigger one with other autobots or decepticons that create arms and legs.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: indeed, I think those are the only two options. But which is it? If it is a mistake, it is spectacularly stupid.

Comment: Even worse, they never sold the extra aerialbot here in the netherlands (at least not to my knowledge) or any of the other stunticons so unless I want to pay some hefty shipping costs, superion is stuck with dragstrip

Comment: Another Hasbro error: on the (otherwise really nice) [new website](https://transformers.hasbro.com/en-gb/brands/combiner-wars), Groove is shown as being part of Defensor (and as a motorbike!). But he wasn't: that was only the case in the Takara version. On the Hasbro version, the G1 character Groove was replaced by "Rook" (Yes, there was a later smaller Groove bike as the sixth component, sold separately, but on the site he is shown as being one of the limbs.)

Comment: I was the kid who devoured everything Transformers, and stared at a lot of advertisements for the toys. It was not uncommon for people making the ads to have no idea how these things worked. Often enough they couldn't even transform individual pieces properly. **tl;dr**: people who didn't know how they worked and didn't really care were only given a bunch of models and told to take pictures.

Answer (score 7):

This combination of four Aerialbots and Dragstrip was never actually sold as "Superion".

While Dragstrip was shipped alongside four Aerialbots in the first wave of Combiner Wars toys, and the art on the back of the packages showed Superion with Drag Strip combined as one arm, this was merely billed as a diagram of how the *toys* could be combined - not as a representation of the *character* Superion.

As seen below, each package only advertises this combined robot with a multilingual label suggesting that these toys can be combined - it does not provide any name for the combined robot in question:

[image]

In the second wave of Combiner Wars toys, including one Aerialbot and four Stunticons, this was no longer the case - now, each figure had a diagram of the combined robot it is meant to be part of on the package, along with that robot's name.

As you can see, the one Aerialbot included in the second wave not only has "Superion" named on the package, but the diagram has also been modified to include that toy - Air Raid - in the correct position, instead of Dragstrip. Likewise, the diagram of Menasor does not include an Aerialbot.

[image]

Likewise, when Quickslinger and Brake-Neck were released exclusively via web retailers, they also included the names and accurate diagrams as featured in the second wave of toys.

[image]

All future waves of toys in Combiner Wars included the four arm and leg components of each combined robot, shipping together, and the packages from each wave showed an accurate diagram of the combined robot along with its name.

In short:

- The diagram showing Dragstrip combined with four components of Superion was only used for the very first release of Combiner Wars toys.
- Hasbro markedly avoided the use of the name Superion on those toys' packages.
- On all future Combiner Wars releases, Hasbro used accurate names and diagrams for each combined robot in its traditional configuration.

From these facts, it seems evident that Dragstrip was never intended to be part of Superion. Rather, Hasbro merely communicated that the Dragstrip toy could be combined with the four Superion components that were currently available at the time.

(Of course, this leaves an underlying question - "Why was the Dragstrip toy shipped earlier than the other Stunticon toys, and why was Air Raid shipped later than the other Aerialbots toys?" - but that is clearly a matter of corporate logistics, as Hasbro distinctly avoided connecting it to the Transformers fiction as presented on the toy packaging.)

Comment: [This image](http://www.tmnttoys.com/reviews/transformers/aerialbots/6541.jpg) is of Silverbolt's packaging. It mentions Superion (on the left) and shows the combined robots including Drag Strip (on the right). Furthermore, I don't see how your answer addresses the original question of *why* Hasbro did this: was it a mistake or a deliberate decision?

Comment: @Wikis Sure, Silverbolt's descriptive paragraph mentions Superion, but it doesn't mention Dragstrip being part of Superion. And the combination diagram isn't labelled as Superion - in contrast to every CW package illustration that depicted the traditional combinations. Your question is "Why is Dragstrip included as part of Superion?" The answer is that your question's underlying assumption is incorrect - Dragstrip was never part of Superion, because there is never any depiction that contains Dragstrip and is labelled as Superion.

Comment: *"Why was Drag Strip sold with four Aerialbots instead of selling all five Aerialbots together?"*

Comment: @Wikis That would be a different question, as it doesn't involve Superion or the Transformers fiction at all - it's merely a quirk of retail distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Variety. Simple as that. If you had four similar-looking Aerialbot figures, it likely wouldn't have had them flown off the shelves as easily as one would expect. Plus, this would allow a bit of encouragement for other collectors to mix and match their gestalt and even prepare fans to start building up to Menasor.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to contradict the existing answer, which shows that the combination including Dragstrip was not identified as Superion, but when an additional Aerialbot was released, the combination of the five of them *was* labelled as Superion.  Can you provide any evidence your answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

It's entirely to advertise that the Combiner Wars figures were "Scramble City" style, in that any deluxe size figure can be either an arm or a leg for any of the voyager size figure torsos. That's it. That's all there is to it. It wasn't some secret way to sneak a Decepticon into an Autobot combiner like they did when they added Prowl to Devastator, It was simply to advertise the play system.

Comment: Are you just guessing here, or is this based on information from an official source? If you do have a source, this answer would be greatly improved if you edited it to specify the source.